# Suppressing FaceVertexCData warning message in matlab

Tags: matlab, printing, 3d, plot, matlab-figure

I recently updated my version of Matlab and since then I have been getting a warning message while using `shading flat;` The warning is:

```
Warning: Patch FaceVertexCData of size 0 cannot be used with Flat shading.
```

First off, the figures being produced look exactly as they should, but it still worries me. Could someone explain what this means or if it is important?

Secondly, if it is NOT important then how can I suppress the warning?

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet to reproduce the `FaceVertexCData` warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering part 2 of your question.  First run:

```
warning on verbose
```

Then the next time you get the warning you will get an exact message describing how to disable that warning in the future.  (The command will look like `warning off <some_long_string>`.)

---

More coarsely, you can simply use

```
warning off
```

Which turns off ALL warnings, but this is considered bad practice, since many warnings are very useful.

Comment: Or just add `warning off` before the relevant line and then `warning on` after that.

Comment: I tried using 'warning off' but it still displays the same warning message. Also, when using 'warning on verbose' is the warning string only displayed on the first warning of that type? Because there are so many warning messages that I can't see the first one (I'm running matlab from the command line by the way).

Comment: I've never had a problem disabling warnings before, ... this is very odd.  Perhaps a function is displaying a "warning" string without using an actual warning object.  Can you post some example code that reproduces this problem?

Comment: I will post my code, however it is part of a large software package. I'm not sure how to replicate the warning message in another situation...maybe i can save a .mat file with all the variables passed to my function 'TEC_plot.m'. Give me just a minute to do that.

Comment: found the problem. It turns out the flat shading warning was actually coming from the print function rather than from actually setting shading to flat....stupid mistake on my part. Thanks for all your help!